# Theorem 9.24 Browder's Introduction to Mathematical Analysis

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

[image]

Putting $A=E$ in $\mu^*(A)+\epsilon=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}[\lambda(F_n^{'} \cap E) + \lambda(F_n^{'} \cap E^{c})]$

We get  $\mu^*(E)+\epsilon=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}[\lambda(F_n^{'} \cap E) + \lambda(F_n^{'} \cap E^{c})]\geq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}[\lambda(F_n^{'} \cap E)]$

I am not getting $\mu^*(E) \geq \lambda(E)$ or How $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}[\lambda(F_n^{'} \cap E)]=\lambda(E)$?

Thanks in advance!